# Read data from a TCP Connection

Tags: web, tcp, windows-server-2008, tcplistener

I'm currently working on a project involving data transfers via TC Protocol.

My OS is Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.

First of all, I have to admit that I'm quite newbie in terms of network stuff.
Despite this, I've already installed a Webserver (very easy thanks to Windows Platform and Internet).

A group of other students must connect to the server by TCP and send data which will only be strings. They are working with a non-user-friendly language ([CC864 command](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telit.com%2Fmodule%2Finfopool%2Fdownload.php%3Fid%3D1603&ei=w2uvUfi3MqL0iQKy6oHgDg&usg=AFQjCNFw6A0tBc1BxUVOQwnSkwc2By_dWA&sig2=Fwm-L4WOoxNYCSUtWh0v_Q&bvm=bv.47380653,d.cGE&cad=rja)).

Right now, they can connect to the server, and I can see them connecting (three-way handshake) thanks to wireshark : http://oi44.tinypic.com/30kbs6r.jpg

I read a lot of documentation without finding a direct answer to this simple question : does it already exist an application listening to the port and getting the data from these if some data are sent ?
I would be astonished if no. But if no, what do you advice me to do ? I saw many websites explaining how to create a listener and receiver server in C# for example.

The thing is : it's strange that with a web server which already listens to the incoming connections and treats not very simple requests, there is not receiving and saving simple TCP requests...

I hope I've been as clear as possible.
I apologize for my approximate english, and I thank you for your time.

Bye

Comment: Web Server deals with HTTP which is one layer on top of TCP.  Are your clients sending HTTP Requests?  Are you supposed to handle HTTP or just TCP?  If TCP, then then the Web Server isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar project for my degree dissertation:

`C# TCP/IP Protocol Stack for Testing Network Applications`

Basically if you want to be able to listen to TCP communications in another program (without using low level (and sometimes undocumented) winapi calls I recommend you learn SharpPcap which is a wrapper for WinPcap used in Wireshark.

The reason you can't directly intercept TCP traffic is that your current networking stack is of course not readily able to be 'sniffed' which is essentially what you are trying to do (by trying to read TCP data from the networking stack) and the SharpPCap kernel mode driver sorts this out by adding an extra 'layer' which passes the data through to your normal network stack AND allows you to sniff.

This is a great subject and a lot of fun (with many real world applications)

Good luck and HTH

Comment: If you want to have a read of my disseration I do have a copy including the TCP/IP Stream sequencer which may be a good start for you to trawl through.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I will take a look to SharpPCap.

I think it's an interesting topic too, but my bosses don't give me any clues to know where to start (i'm intern).

Concerning your dissertation, I'd be glad to read it.

Comment: @user2456624 inbox me your email address and I'll send digital copy

Comment: I don't know how to send pm so : kevin.leprin@free.fr is one of my adresses.